# "DiskImageNotReady" error when creating VM in Azure using ARM template and JSON

Tags: json, powershell, azure, cloud

I am trying to deploy 3 azure Ubuntu vm's using an ARM template. They are being deployed as part of a larger infrastructure deployment of resource groups, storage accounts, SQL servers etc. Everything is working great apart from the VM creation. During testing with a single VM the script worked but with 3 I get the following error -

```
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 16:52:57 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'xxxV3Monitor1' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "DiskImageNotReady",
        "message": "Disk image https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/rootvhd/v1ubuntudocker.vhd is in Pending state. Please retry when image is ready."
      }
```

It seems the custom root VHD image we a re using is failing due to be in a "Pending" state, i assume this is some lock on the file as it is being used to create one of the other VMs?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To add, I have tried setting each VM to have a dependency of the previous one to stagger the builds but this doesn't appear to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are moving the VM image prior to creating the VM's from it.
If so try this code after the move, and before you start the deployment script:
($blob1 is the variable that you call the Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy command)

```
### Retrieve the current status of the copy operation ###
$status = $blob1 | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState 

### Print out status ### 
$status 

### Loop until complete ###                                    
While($status.Status -eq "Pending"){
  $status = $blob1 | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState 
  Start-Sleep -s 60
  ### Print out status ###
  $status
}
```

This will cycle each minute updating with the status.